# Getting a Status Code of 0 when Calling HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data.toString());
        wr.flush();
        status = con.getResponseCode();
```

This code is part of an AsyncTask class in Android Studio. When I execute a Post request using PostMan, the status returned is 200; however, when I make the request using the android emulator, the status is returned as 0. I'm super confused, and some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 0 means some kind of network error.
Try checking for:

- Internet permission
- Emulator, Connectivity

Comment: I have internet permission and connectivity; when I execute the POST request, the data is sent correctly (it goes properly to the database). However, the status code is returned as 0.